# can't locate node [my_imu] in package [imu_localisation]

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to make a simple cpp code that does the double integration for an IMU to return the  estimated position. The package `imu_localisation`  is listed in `rospack list`, and `roslaunch` finds the package and the launch file as well. However when I try to launch it I am hit with:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [imu_localisation/my_imu]: can't locate node [my_imu] in package [imu_localisation]
```

I've tried `catkin_make` and `source devel/setup.bash` in that order multiple times to no avail.
The error occurs when I run

```
roslaunch imu_localisation localise.launch
```

The following is the `my_imu.cpp` code.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/Imu.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Vector3.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"

sensor_msgs::Imu prev_imu;

void imuCallback(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& imu){
  prev_imu.linear_acceleration.x = imu->linear_acceleration.x;
  prev_imu.linear_acceleration.y = imu->linear_acceleration.y;
  prev_imu.linear_acceleration.z = imu->linear_acceleration.z;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_imu");
  double samplePeriod = 0.02;
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  geometry_msgs::Vector3 vel,prev_vel,pos,prev_pos;
  ros::Publisher pos_pub=nh.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("/odom",1);
  ros::Subscriber imu_sub=nh.subscribe("/imu/data" , 50, imuCallback);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(50);

  while(ros::ok()){
    std_msgs::String msgs;
    if(prev_vel.x == 0){
      prev_vel.x = prev_imu.linear_acceleration.x * samplePeriod;
      prev_vel.y = prev_imu.linear_acceleration.y * samplePeriod;
      prev_vel.z = prev_imu.linear_acceleration.z * samplePeriod;
    }
    //
    vel.x = prev_vel.x + prev_imu.linear_acceleration.x * samplePeriod;
    vel.y = prev_vel.y + prev_imu.linear_acceleration.y * samplePeriod;
    vel.z = prev_vel.z + prev_imu.linear_acceleration.z * samplePeriod;
    ROS_INFO("vel x : %f", vel.x);
    pos.x = prev_pos.x + vel.x * samplePeriod;
    pos.y = prev_pos.y + vel.y * samplePeriod;
    pos.z = prev_pos.z + vel.z * samplePeriod;
    ROS_INFO("pos x : %f", pos.x);

    prev_vel = vel;
    prev_pos = pos;
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }

}
```

And here is my launch file **localise.launch**

```
<launch>

  <node pkg="imu_localisation" name="my_imu" type="my_imu" output="screen">
  </node>
</launch>
```

And the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(imu_localisation)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package()

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(imu_localisation src/my_imu.cpp)
add_dependencies(imu_localisation ${imu_localisation_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(imu_localisation
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Any pointers? I'm sure I'm missing something dead simple here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329355/can%27t-locate-node-%5Bmy_imu%5D-in-package-%5Bimu_localisation%5D/) by [Aerugo2272](https://answers.ros.org/users/44305/aerugo2272/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a small error in your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
add_executable(imu_localisation src/my_imu.cpp)
```

This section is telling catkin_make to build the `src/my_imu.cpp` code into a node called `imu_localisation`, you're launch file is looking for a node called `my_imu` which is never being created.

If you update this line as shown below and rebuild your package this should start working.

```
add_executable(my_imu src/my_imu.cpp)
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aerugo2272](https://answers.ros.org/users/44305/aerugo2272/) on 2019-07-29**:
Thanks that worked! Small note, had to change the name in "add_dependencies" and "target_link_libraries" as well to my node name rather than the package name catkin_create_package gives it by default.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-30**:
That is very true, I missed that one.

Glad it's fixed.